# SQL statement on event rule

Tags: sql, oracle11g, erp, jde, jdedwards

It's possible to run an SQL statement into an event rule? I've been tryin but seems it's not possible

PD: It's possible to code using just keyboard, without mouse?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: I just got one fetch single, then I use this result to get another fetch signle in another table.. It's not efficient

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to write sql inside event rules, this is by design, JDE support different database and there is an abstraction layer that translate jde specific code (c api or ER) into platform specific SQL.

Event Rules support Table IO through a JDE native visual future (select table, maps fields and conditions, etc...). Look at official documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've used SELECT SUM before by using a dropped table/BSVW.
You create the table in E1 and then DROP it on the DB. 
Create your SQL with the same name as the BSVW and then you can use the BSVW in E1 which performs you SQL.

I guess it kind of depends what the SQL actually is.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I didn't explain myself correctly or I don''t understand your response, I want to run an sql statement like 'SELECT * FROM F111 WHERE A>B'

Answer (score 0):

If we use the ER table command, it will be converted to SQL statemnt.
So instead of SQL, you can use the ER Table I/Os.

Comment: Yes, this is how I'm doing now. But also I want to write an SQL statement for another more complex operations. Regards.